# matched parentheses in hyperlinks are not handled correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, formatting

When a hyperlink contains a `(` character that is matched at the end of the URL by a `)` character, AskUbuntu should recognize that the final `)` character is part of the URL. However, currently that is not the case, for example:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)

I noticed this bug when revising a post (see the original revision [here](https://askubuntu.com/posts/149457/revisions)).

Of course, it's important that a fix for this bug not be *overzealous* in recognizing trailing `)` characters as part of URL's. An unmatched `)` at the end of a URL (i.e., one that does not have a corresponding `(` character *earlier in the URL*) should not be taken as part of the URL. URL's are frequently present at the end of parentheses-enclosed text, and it would be bad to break that currently-working functionality. For example, this behavior should not be changed:

> Wikipedia has an article on URL's (at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [URL detecting error with address like "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66472/url-detecting-error-with-address-like-http-en-wikipedia-org-wiki-octet-compu/165064#165064) on Meta Stack Overflow for details; long story short: After the next build of the site, this will work as you had expected.

Comment: Glad to hear it, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**This is indeed a bug, and should be addressed.**

---

There's a workaround, though...

```
[Wikipedia - Ubuntu (Operating System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system))
```

yields this:

[Wikipedia - Ubuntu (Operating System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)